# Change appender level instead of the logger level

Tags: spring-boot, log4j2, spring-boot-admin

My team uses [`Spring Boot Admin`](https://github.com/codecentric/spring-boot-admin) for controlling our `spring application`,
In `Spring Boot Admin` we have the option to change the [`logger`](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/configuration.html#Additivity) level in `Runtime`,
we have a separate logger for each `task`(Thread), and if we want to see the console logs only for one thread we turning off all the other threads loggers,
The problem is that each logger sends it's output both for the `STDOUT` and also for a certain file, and we want to turn off **only** the stdout output.

**log4j2.xml configuration example:**

```
<Loggers>
   <Logger name="task1" level="info">
     <AppenderRef ref="Console"/>
     <AppenderRef ref="File"/>
   </Logger>
   <Logger name="task2" level="info">
     <AppenderRef ref="Console"/>
     <AppenderRef ref="File"/>
   </Logger>
</Loggers>
```

we tried a lot of solutions:

- use parent loggers combined with additivity, and separate each appender to different logger,
  Any ideas about it?

Comment: Are you able to add a separate Logger for console and File appender?
Like :

<Logger name="task1Console" level="info">
     <AppenderRef ref="Console"/>
     <AppenderRef ref="File"/>
   </Logger>
<Logger name="task1File" level="info">
     <AppenderRef ref="File"/>
</Logger>

Comment: Can you add code related with task/thread?

Answer (score 2):

Log4j2 does not allow to manage System.out and System.err streams by default.

To clarify how console logger works:
Simply `Console` appender prints its output to System.out or System.err. According to documentation, if you do not specify target by default it will print to System.out:

https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/appenders.html

> target || String || Either "SYSTEM_OUT" or "SYSTEM_ERR". The default is "SYSTEM_OUT".

---

**Here is an example:**

`log4j2.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <Properties>
        <Property name="log-pattern">%d{ISO8601} %-5p %m\n</Property>
    </Properties>
    <appenders>
        <Console name="Console" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
            <PatternLayout>
                <pattern>${log-pattern}</pattern>
            </PatternLayout>
        </Console>
    </appenders>
    <Loggers>
        <logger name="testLogger" level="info" additivity="false">
            <AppenderRef ref="Console"/>
        </logger>
    </Loggers>
</configuration>
```

`LogApp.java`

```
import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger;

public class LogApp {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Logger log = LogManager.getLogger("testLogger");
        log.info("Logger output test!");
        System.out.println("System out test!");
    }
}
```

Output:

```
2019-01-08T19:08:57,587 INFO  Logger output test!
System out test!
```

---

**A Workaround To Manage System Streams**

Take Dmitry Pavlenko's stream redirection class

https://sysgears.com/articles/how-to-redirect-stdout-and-stderr-writing-to-a-log4j-appender/

```
import org.apache.logging.log4j.Level;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStream;

/**
  * A change was made on the existing code:
  * - At (LoggingOutputStream#flush) method 'count' could contain 
  *  single space character, this types of logs has been skipped
  */
public class LoggingOutputStream extends OutputStream {
    private static final int DEFAULT_BUFFER_LENGTH = 2048;
    private boolean hasBeenClosed = false;
    private byte[] buf;
    private int count;

    private int curBufLength;

    private Logger log;

    private Level level;

    public LoggingOutputStream(final Logger log,
                               final Level level)
            throws IllegalArgumentException {
        if (log == null || level == null) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                    "Logger or log level must be not null");
        }
        this.log = log;
        this.level = level;
        curBufLength = DEFAULT_BUFFER_LENGTH;
        buf = new byte[curBufLength];
        count = 0;
    }

    public void write(final int b) throws IOException {
        if (hasBeenClosed) {
            throw new IOException("The stream has been closed.");
        }
        // don't log nulls
        if (b == 0) {
            return;
        }
        // would this be writing past the buffer?
        if (count == curBufLength) {
            // grow the buffer
            final int newBufLength = curBufLength +
                    DEFAULT_BUFFER_LENGTH;
            final byte[] newBuf = new byte[newBufLength];
            System.arraycopy(buf, 0, newBuf, 0, curBufLength);
            buf = newBuf;
            curBufLength = newBufLength;
        }

        buf[count] = (byte) b;
        count++;
    }

    public void flush() {
        if (count <= 1) {
            count = 0;
            return;
        }
        final byte[] bytes = new byte[count];
        System.arraycopy(buf, 0, bytes, 0, count);
        String str = new String(bytes);
        log.log(level, str);
        count = 0;
    }

    public void close() {
        flush();
        hasBeenClosed = true;
    }
}
```

And create a custom logger for system output stream, than register it.

Here is the complete code of the logger usage:

`log4j2.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <Properties>
        <Property name="log-pattern">%d{ISO8601} %-5p %m\n</Property>
    </Properties>
    <appenders>
        <Console name="Console" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
            <PatternLayout>
                <pattern>${log-pattern}</pattern>
            </PatternLayout>
        </Console>
    </appenders>
    <Loggers>
        <logger name="testLogger" level="info" additivity="false">
            <AppenderRef ref="Console"/>
        </logger>
        <logger name="systemOut" level="info" additivity="true"/>
    </Loggers>
</configuration>
```

`SystemLogging.java`

```
import org.apache.logging.log4j.Level;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;

import java.io.PrintStream;

public class SystemLogging {
    public void enableOutStreamLogging() {
        System.setOut(createPrintStream("systemOut", Level.INFO));
    }

    private PrintStream createPrintStream(String name, Level level) {
        return new PrintStream(new LoggingOutputStream(LogManager.getLogger(name), level), true);
    }
}
```

`LogApp.java`

```
import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger;

public class LogApp {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new SystemLogging().enableOutStreamLogging();

        Logger log = LogManager.getLogger("testLogger");
        log.info("Logger output test!");
        System.out.println("System out test!");
    }
}
```

Final output

```
2019-01-08T19:30:43,456 INFO  Logger output test!
19:30:43.457 [main] INFO  systemOut - System out test!
```

---

Now, customize system out with new logger configuration as you wish.

Plus; if you don't want to override `System.out` and just want to save it: there is [TeeOutputStream](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/javadocs/api-2.5/org/apache/commons/io/output/TeeOutputStream.html) in [commons-io](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/) library. You can just replace original `System.out` with a combination of original `System.out` and `LoggingOutputStream` that will write simultaniously to both streams. This won't change the original output but allow you to save `System.out` with a logging appender.